# how can i make this graphql extrutured folder style work

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, adonis.js

when i try to get the data from db i get:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.getCategorias.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getCategorias"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i'm using postgres as DB

check the code in github repo: https://github.com/Coyas/apollo-graphql-adonis-boilerplate

Comment: Your question is not very clear , are you looking for schema definition ?

Comment: i just want to understand why my schemas does not work as expected